# Find the limit of the following sequence or determine that the limit does not exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If:

$b_n = \begin{cases}
\frac {n+4}{n}: n > 5200 \\
ne^{-n}: n \le 5200 \\
\end{cases}$

The final answer should be 1, but I can't finish the problem all the way, here's what I have so far:

$$\int_{5201}^{∞} \frac{x+4}{x}dx$$

= lim b→∞ [x+ 4lnx] 5201 to ∞

= lim b→∞ [(b + 4lnb) - (5201 + 4ln5201)]

= [(∞ + 4ln∞) - (5201 + 4ln5201)]

= ???

Then I did:

$$\int_{-∞}^{5200} xe^{-x}dx$$

u= x

du= dx

dv = e<sup>-x</sup>

v = -e<sup>-x</sup>

=lim a→-∞[-xe<sup>-x</sup> - e<sup>-x</sup>] a to 5200

=lim a→-∞[(-5200e<sup>-5200</sup> - e<sup>-5200</sup>) - (-ae<sup>-a</sup> - e<sup>-a</sup>)]

= ???

I don't even think I approached the problem correctly, I took a guess at the method used to solve it, but I don't know if I'm on the right track. Again, the answer is supposed to be 1. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The limit of a sequence means the limit as $n \to +\infty$. That being the case, to figure out the limit of a sequence, you only need to consider $n$ sufficiently large. A domain of a sequence is a subset of the natural numbers, so you shouldn't be dealing with negative $n$ at all. Consider the question as asking $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\langle \frac {n+4} {n}\rangle$ and ignore everything about what happens for small $n$.